# Code not working inside "addEventListener" using javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone i am making drag and drop web application. I am not able to run console.log("Dragging element"); inside addEventListener. Can anyone help me with this.
Below are 2 files that i have made yet

**index.js**

```
const dropZone=document.querySelector(".drop-zone");
dropZone.addEventListener("dragover",(e)=>{
    console.log("Dragging element");
})
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>inShare - Easy file sharing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="upload-container">
        <div class="drop-zone">
            <div class="icon-container">
                <img src="./file.svg" alt="File icon" draggable="false" class="center">
                <img src="./file.svg" alt="File icon" draggable="false" class="left">
                <img src="./file.svg" alt="File icon" draggable="false" class="right">
            </div>
            <div class="title">Drop your files or,<span class="browseBtn">browse</span></div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this works fine for me if you just make your items draggable (draggable = true)

Comment: @syder still not working for me

Comment: I get the Listener fired when I select something in .drop-zone and then drag it. Try it with the text for example

Comment: Not working on chrome so tried with brave it worked thanks everyone